# ASP.NET HttpPost not passing Dictionary object into Action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, http-post

I am having trouble retrieving a Collection class in the HttPost method in my Controller code.
For some reason it is a able to retrieve an 'int', for example, but not a Dictionary.

I am using a hidden Input tag in the ASPX file.
I did put a Debug.WriteLine before and after the HTTP post in the ASPX file and the Controller page but the Dictionary is only populated in the ASPX page. It's 0 for the code page where I need it.

```
...</tr>
                <% i++; %>
                <% list.Add(user.ID.ToString()); %>
                <% list.Add(user.FirstName.ToString()); %>
                <% list.Add(user.LastName.ToString()); %>
                <% list.Add(user.Seniority.ToString()); %>
                <% list.Add(sec_a.ToString()); %>
                <% list.Add(sec_b.ToString()); %>
                <% list.Add(sec_c.ToString()); %>
                <% list.Add(uvid_a.ToString()); %>
                <% details.Add(i, list); %>
             <% } %>
         </tbody>
         </table>
          // it works here but not in the .CS file where the post is made
        <% System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Before Post value: " + details.Count); %>
          // here is the hidden field that is supposed to send the variable into the Action method
        <input type="hidden" name="student_details" value="<%= details %>" />
        <div class="buttons">
<button type="submit" class="button">Export Data</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</article>
```

```
    //Controller file    
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Report(Dictionary<int, List<string>> student_details)
    {
        var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
        var datatable = new DataTable();

        datatable.Columns.Add("User ID");
        datatable.Columns.Add("First Name");
        datatable.Columns.Add("Last Name");
        datatable.Columns.Add("xxx");
        datatable.Columns.Add("yyy");
        datatable.Columns.Add("zzz");
        datatable.Columns.Add("Title");
        datatable.Columns.Add("Grade");

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("After Post value: " + student_details.Count);

        foreach (var stud in student_details)
        {
            datatable.Rows.Add(stud.Value);
        }
```

It passes an int variable but not a Dictionary.

Comment: Why would you do such a thing? Passing data originated from server side to client side, only to pass it back? And you can't just echo out a .NET dictionary object to HTML form and expect it to be converted to .NET dictionary object again. View source and by default you will see the the value of `student_details` = `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.String] `

Comment: I understand. Got it. I will just do everything in the Controller class. Thanks.